# Hog mode / Exclusive access to audio output device with SoX

Tags: macos, core-audio, sox, libsox

I would like to know whether SoX/LibSoX offers the possibility to access a sound device in exclusive/hog mode. The idea is to prevent other applications from accessing the sound card / DAC that is being used by the focal app.

My main target is OSX CoreAudio output, but I am also eager to know about Linux (OSS/Alsa).

I know this is possible in CoreAudio, because I have seen it implemented in several apps, including [this open source one](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/7c032bde3e6473902bbda2aea65be4bfb9d68802/audio/out/ao_coreaudio_exclusive.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X at least, the answer appears to be no.  In http://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/src/coreaudio.c SoX uses the default input or output device but there is no provision for hog mode.

Comment: SoX can open manually specified devices as well -- see line 137 and on. But you are right, it doesn't seem to contain any provision for an eventual hog mode. Someone should probably do it one day...